# Cout Not Printing Contents of Pointed To Memory

Tags: c++, memory, cout

I have the following code:

```
if (myFile.is_open()) {
    int i = 0;
    while (myFile.good()) {
        char *ptr = &(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mem[0]))[i];
        myFile.read(ptr, sizeof(struct req));
        cout << ptr << endl;
        i += sizeof(struct req);
    }
}
```

The cout in the loop here seems to print nothing, although I know that the code is definitely setting the memory because it prints out the correct values if I do something like `cout << mem[5]` instead. Basically, I just want to print the contents of whatever `ptr` is referring to. This is probably a silly question, but anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Is `mem[0]` by any chance `'\0'`?

Comment: What is the type of `myFile`?

Comment: @Bingo It's a .bin file.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @Luchian: You meant `ptr[0]`, right?  `mem[0]` has structure type evidently.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Seems like you rarely miss an opportunity to tell someone to study C++ from a book. I know what a null terminator is - I just didn't initially see why you asked what you asked.

Comment: @JohnRoberts I rarely miss the opportunity to give good advice, yes. Do you think learning from a book is bad, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout << ptr`, if `ptr` is of type `char*`, treats `ptr` as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string, and it prints the contents of that string up to, but not including, the terminating `'\0'` null character.

If you want to print the pointer value, convert to `void*`:

```
cout << (void*)ptr << ...
```

That's assuming you actuallly want to print the value of the pointer, which will probably appear as a hexadecimal memory address. Your title says "Contents of Pointer", which would be the memory address (the contents of the pointer object itself). If instead you want to print the data that the pointer points to, please update your question to make it clearer just what you want to print and in what format.

Comment: I see. What if I want to see the contents of what the pointer is pointing to instead?

Comment: I've updated the question. I just want to print the contents of the memory address that ptr is pointing to.

Comment: @JohnRoberts: Print the contents how? As characters? As numbers?

Comment: As numbers would be better.

Answer (score 2):

`cout << ptr` will print `ptr` as if it pointed to a C string. Thus, if it hits a NUL character, it will stop. For example, if you try `cout << "hello\0world"`, you will only see `hello` appear.

Consider writing a hexdump of the memory region instead if you want to see its contents.

Comment: or use `cout.write(ptr, sizeof(struct req))`

Comment: This crashed the program for some reason.